# Building a conditional text string based on the attribute values not found in the for-each loop

Tags: xslt-1.0

This this `for-each` snippet:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$HistDB//AssignmentHistory/*/StudentItems/Item/Name[@Counsel and .=$strName]">
    <!-- Sort by counsel number (ascending) -->
    <xsl:sort select="@Counsel" data-type="number"/>

    <!-- Then sort by date (ascending) -->
    <xsl:sort select="local-name(../../..)"/>

    <tr>
        <!-- Counsel -->
        <td class="counsel">
            <xsl:value-of select="@Counsel"/>
        </td>
        <!-- Date DD/MM/YYYY -->
        <td class="counsel">
            <xsl:variable name="strWeek" select="local-name(../../..)"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring($strWeek, 8, 2)"/>
            <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring($strWeek, 5, 2)"/>
            <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring($strWeek, 2, 4)"/>
        </td>
    </tr>

</xsl:for-each>
```

It displays output (with formatting) like this:

[image]

All the counsel numbers will be in the range 1 - 20. I would like to show a comma separated list after my table for the counsel numbers that the student has not done. In the above example I would like to see:

> Not assigned: 1, 3, 4, 6, 9, 11, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20

I support my XSL here could be stripped down to a simple text case. But can what I want to do be achieved with XSLT-1?

---

I am trying to adopt the suggested answer with:

```
<xsl:variable name="missing-items">
    <xsl:call-template name="list-missing-items">
        <xsl:with-param name="items" select ="$HistDB//AssignmentHistory/*/StudentItems/Item/Name[@Counsel and .=$strName]"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>
<missing-items>
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(normalize-space($missing-items), ' ', ',')" />
</missing-items>
```

But all 20 numbers are being listed.

Comment: Which XSLT 1.0 processor are you using? Some extension functions could be useful here, if your processor supports them.

Comment: @michael.hor257k This script is being executed directed within a `WebView2` browser control to display the HTML output on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following **simplified** example:

**XML**

```
<root>
    <item>2</item>
    <item>2</item>
    <item>5</item>
    <item>7</item>
    <item>10</item>
    <item>10</item>
    <item>10</item>
    <item>10</item>
    <item>12</item>
</root>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:variable name="missing-items">
        <xsl:call-template name="list-missing-items">
            <xsl:with-param name="items" select="item"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <missing-items>
        <xsl:value-of select="translate(normalize-space($missing-items), ' ', ',')" />
    </missing-items>    
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="list-missing-items">
    <xsl:param name="items"/>
    <xsl:param name="max" select="20"/>
    <xsl:if test="$max > 1">
        <xsl:call-template name="list-missing-items">
            <xsl:with-param name="items" select="$items"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="max" select="$max - 1"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="not($max=$items)">
        <xsl:value-of select="$max" />
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<missing-items>1,3,4,6,8,9,11,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20</missing-items>
```

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to port this into my script but it is listing all 20 numbers. Please see my updated question.

Comment: I have no way to reproduce your problem and therefore do not know what causes it. If I had to guess, I would say you probably did not make the necessary adjustment to compare `$max` to the value of the `@Counsel` attribute instead of the value of the parent `Name` element.

Comment: Gotcha! Now I understand. Changed it like this: `<xsl:if test="count($items[@Counsel=$max]) = 0">`.

Comment: I believe you could have done simply `<xsl:if test="not($max=$items/@Counsel)">` or perhaps even simpler, use `<xsl:with-param name="items" select="$HistDB//AssignmentHistory/*/StudentItems/Item/Name[@Counsel and .=$strName]/@Counsel"/>`. Again, untested because ...

Comment: I used your first choice. Does work. Thanks. 